# In Python IDLE How to replace one character in regex search in replace dialog?

Tags: regex, replace, python-idle

Let's say I have bunch of lines like this:

```
file.write('string')
```

and want to rewrite them fast into

```
text += 'string'
```

I can replace the `file.write(` part without using regex because I want to replace all such occurrences. But for the ending part, how can I do it using the Python IDLE replace dialog window? I can find it using `(file.write).*(\)$)` but now I want to replace just the last character. Is there some trick to be able to do that instead of just replacing the whole thing?

[image]

Comment: I know it can be done in Notepad++ and VSCode, but I don't know about IDLE.

Comment: normally you have to use `( )` to catch string and later use `\1` to put it back. I would uise find: `file.write\((.*)\)$`and replace: `text += \1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`( )` has special meaning in regex and you should use it in different way.

You should use `( )` with `.*` to catch `'string'` and later put it as `\1` in new code.

Because `( )` has special meaning so I use `\(` and `\)` to skip original `( )` in code.

Find: `file.write\((.*)\)$`

Replace: `text += \1`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had never thought to test if back-references work.  I opened https://bugs.python.org/issue45199, "IDLE: document search (find) and replace better", to document the dialogs better.